# Can't access .gz file as static files from express app with Nginx

Tags: nginx, vps

I have an express app on folder `/home/xxx/example.com/public_html/APIBackend`, on this app I have a folder for static files at `/home/xxx/example.com/public_html/APIBackend/sitemapfiles` which includes some `.gz` files.

In the express app, I have code to serve static files like this:

`app.use('/sitemapfiles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../sitemapfiles'))) // works on localhost`

But when access gz files from domain like *example.com/sitemapfiles/sitemap.gz*, it shows 404 err from Ngnix. So I think the issue is from Ngnix, I have Ngnix config files as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/xxx/example.com/public_html;

    location / {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Client-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/extra/staticfiles.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/extra/security.conf;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404;
    error_page 404 /hvn_404.html;

    root /home/xxx/example.com/public_html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Client-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/extra/staticfiles.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/extra/security.conf;
}
```

staticfiles.conf

```
location = /favicon.ico { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|webp)$ {
    gzip_static off;
    brotli_static off;
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800";
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
    break;
}
location ~* \.(3gp|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
    gzip_static off;
    brotli_static off;
    sendfile off;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800";
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
    break;
}
location ~* \.(js)$ {
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800";
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
    break;
}
location ~* \.(css)$ {
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800";
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
    break;
}
location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
    break;
}
```

security.conf

```
location ^~ /GponForm/ { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location ^~ /GponForm/diag_Form { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
# Return 403 forbidden for readme.(txt|html) or license.(txt|html) or example.(txt|html) or other common git repository files
location ~*  "/(^$|readme|license|example|LICENSE|README|LEGALNOTICE|INSTALLATION|CHANGELOG)\.(txt|html|md)" {
    deny all;
}
location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|\.user\.ini|\.ht|\.env|\.git|\.svn|\.project) {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
# Deny backup extensions & log files and return 403 forbidden
location ~* "\.(love|error|kid|cgi|old|orig|original|php#|php~|php_bak|save|swo|aspx?|tpl|sh|bash|bak?|cfg|cgi|dll|exe|git|hg|ini|jsp|log|mdb|out|sql|svn|swp|tar|rdf|gz|zip|bz2|7z|pem|asc|conf|dump)$" {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

So how do I serve gz files in this case. I'm new in devOps and just follow tuts online, I don't know much about Ngnix configure.

Thank you for help

---

Update, when I access url like `example.com/APIBackend/sitemapfiles/file.gz`, it works. So how do I make url like `mydomain.com/sitemapfiles/file.gz` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `root` is set to `/home/xxx/example.com/public_html`.

This means, a request for `https://example.com/APIBackend/sitemapfiles/file.gz` will look up files in `/home/xxx/example.com/public_html/APIBackend/sitemapfiles/file.gz`.

If you want to serve the files from a different directory, you need to use `alias` directive:

```
location /sitemapfiles {
    alias /home/xxx/example.com/public_html/APIBackend/sitemapfiles;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Furthermore, your configuration proxies all traffic to your application. None of the `location ~` blocks are applied, due to the way nginx [processes locations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). The `location /` overrides your other locations.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.